# Очень странно ведет себя слайдер

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Вот сайт http://theescape.zone/

Слайды:

- id="lt1"
- id="lt2"
- id="lt3"
- id="lt4"
- id="lt5"

Булеты:

- id="ln1"
- id="ln2"
- id="ln3"
- id="ln4"
- id="ln5"

Свои ID получают правильно, если по ним тыкать - все хорошо, но...

При загрузке страницы начинается автослайд и когда он переходит на `id="lt5"` и `id="ln5"`, то не добавляет класс `img5` к тегу `<img class="head-image">`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()>0){
          $('.header').addClass('affix');
        } else {
          $('.header').removeClass('affix');
        }
      });

$('#ln1').click(function(){
  $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
  $('.line a').removeClass("active");
  $('#ln1').addClass("active");
  $('#lt1').addClass("active");
  $('.head-image').addClass("img1");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
  clearTimeout(timerId);
})

$('#ln2').click(function(){
  $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
  $('.line a').removeClass("active");
  $('#ln2').addClass("active");
  $('#lt2').addClass("active");
  $('.head-image').addClass("img2");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
  clearTimeout(timerId);
})

$('#ln3').click(function(){
  $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
  $('.line a').removeClass("active");
  $('#ln3').addClass("active");
  $('#lt3').addClass("active");
  $('.head-image').addClass("img3");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
  clearTimeout(timerId);
})

$('#ln4').click(function(){
  $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
  $('.line a').removeClass("active");
  $('#ln4').addClass("active");
  $('#lt4').addClass("active");
  $('.head-image').addClass("img4");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
  clearTimeout(timerId);
})

$('#ln5').click(function(){
  $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
  $('.line a').removeClass("active");
  $('#ln5').addClass("active");
  $('#lt5').addClass("active");
  $('.head-image').addClass("img5");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
  $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
  clearTimeout(timerId);
})

var myElement1 = document.getElementsByClassName("head-image")[0];
var mc1 = new Hammer(myElement1);
mc1.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

// listen to events...

    mc1.on("swipeleft", function(ev1) {  
    if ($('#ln5').hasClass("active")) {
          $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
          $('.line a').removeClass("active");
          $('#ln1').addClass("active");
          $('#lt1').addClass("active");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
          $('.head-image').addClass("img1");
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          return false;
        }       
      if ($('#ln4').hasClass("active")) {
          $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
          $('.line a').removeClass("active");
          $('#ln5').addClass("active");
          $('#lt5').addClass("active");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
          $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
          $('.head-image').addClass("img5");
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          return false;
        }       
      if ($('#ln3').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln4').addClass("active");
        $('#lt4').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      } 
      if ($('#ln2').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln3').addClass("active");
        $('#lt3').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img3");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      }
      if ($('#ln1').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln2').addClass("active");
        $('#lt2').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      }

    });

    mc1.on("swiperight", function(ev1) {


      if ($('#ln1').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln5').addClass("active");
        $('#lt5').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      }
      if ($('#ln2').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln1').addClass("active");
        $('#lt1').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img1");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      } 
      if ($('#ln3').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln2').addClass("active");
        $('#lt2').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      }
      if ($('#ln4').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln3').addClass("active");
        $('#lt3').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img3");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      }
      if ($('#ln5').hasClass("active")) {
        $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
        $('.line a').removeClass("active");
        $('#ln4').addClass("active");
        $('#lt4').addClass("active");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
        $('.head-image').addClass("img4");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
        $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        return false;
      }

    });




var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    var $next = $('.block1 .active').removeClass('active').next()
    if ($next.length) {
        $next.addClass('active'); 
    }
    else {
        $("#ln1").addClass('active');
    }
    if ($('#ln1').hasClass("active")) {
      $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
      $('.line a').removeClass("active");
      $('#ln1').addClass("active");
      $('#lt1').addClass("active");
      $('.head-image').addClass("img1");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
    }
    if ($('#ln2').hasClass("active")) {
      $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
      $('.line a').removeClass("active");
      $('#ln2').addClass("active");
      $('#lt2').addClass("active");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
      $('.head-image').addClass("img2");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
    }
    if ($('#ln3').hasClass("active")) {
      $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
      $('.line a').removeClass("active");
      $('#ln3').addClass("active");
      $('#lt3').addClass("active");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
      $('.head-image').addClass("img3");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
    } 

    if ($('#ln4').hasClass("active")) {
      $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
      $('.line a').removeClass("active");
      $('#ln4').addClass("active");
      $('#lt4').addClass("active");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img5");
      $('.head-image').addClass("img4");
    } 

    if ($('#ln5').hasClass("active")) {
      $('.line .text-head').removeClass("active");
      $('.line a').removeClass("active");
      $('#ln5').addClass("active");
      $('#lt5').addClass("active");
      $('.head-image').addClass("img5");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img2");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img3");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img4");
      $('.head-image').removeClass("img1");
    }
      }, 5000);  
    });
```

После очень внимательных поисков была найдена опечатка в JS коде слайдера, но теперь появился еще 1 вопрос:
при загрузке нужно взять цифру из первого элемента булетов и передать значение в `<img class="head-image img<--сюда-->">`

Comment: Когда идет автослайд то img5 не добавляется, то что он замыкается в конце - это второй вопрос и сейчас это не важно

Comment: Это заметно на втором слайде после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: вообще-то img5, а не img3, я все написал в теле сообщения

Comment: Короче, это проблема только с этим слайдом. Как только я его поставил последним, слайдер перестает зацикливаться, но img5 так же не добавляется, я грешу на JS

Comment: Ну естественно это JS, нужно смотреть код.  Может в алгоритме что то не так, может в структуре html  какая ошибка.

Comment: Слайдер - самопис, в структуре html точно нет проблем

Comment: добавил JS слайдера

Comment: Вам самому удобно ориентироваться в этой простыне? Неужели так сложно инкапсулировать общую часть?

Comment: Мне не удобно, но это писалось до меня, теперь придётся переделать все

Comment: Там используется шаблон divi в котором был какой-то код слайдера, потом его типа допилили, а ко мне он уже попал с багами. Моя задача была всего лишь реализовать возможность управлять им из админки, а тут всплыли баги (порядок слайдов менять нельзя - зацикливается слайдер, менять кол-во тоже нельзя)